# Playing Vimeo video using Silverlight MediaElement

Tags: silverlight, vimeo

Is it possible to play videos from Vimeo in Silverlight apps using MediaElement for example? If answer is yes, how?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regardless if it's technically possible or not. Vimeo does not allow their content to be played in anything but their own web player.

Comment: Ok..But I suppose that you need to have some sort of access of video file.. Because I have WP7 app which can play Vimeo videos.. I don't now how or what, but it's playing in WP7 video player... There must be some URL that you can access to play video in mp4 or similar format, without using flash player..

Answer (score 0):

without checking Vimeo's faq I dare to say: not possible. As those videos present some additional user-interaction not supported by the MediaElement control, interaction that Vimeo surely don't want to lose.